# The smallest prime divisor of 18! + 1

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

So I have the following question:

Find the smallest prime divisor of $18!+1$.

In order to solve this I have used Wilson's Theorem as follows:

$$18!=(19-1)!$$

So we have $$(19-1)!+1$$

By Wilson's Theorem $${(19-1)!}\equiv{-1}\pmod{19}$$

And hence we have $$-1+1=0\pmod{19}$$

So $19$ is a divisor of $18!+1$.

Via a prime factorisation calculator I have found that this is in fact, the smallest prime divisor however I'm unsure of how to show this?

Comment: Hint: all primes smaller than $18$ divide $18!$.

Comment: Of course... thanks!

Comment: It is $19$ the smallest prime factor

Comment: $18!+1=19\ 23\ 29\ 61\ 67\ 123610951=6402373705728001$

Answer (score 1):

$$S=18!+1=2.3.4...18+1$$
if $a\in\{2,3,5,7...17\}$ is a prime which divides $ S, $ then it will divides  $ 1$ because it divides $18!$.

So $19$ is the smallest.